# Buildroot rsync change_dir no such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5, buildroot

I'm building an image for Raspberry Pi 3B on Ubuntu using Buildroot. I added some features from Qt5 to my image using make menuconfig but now the build proccess fails:

```
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/home/martin/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt5quickcontrols-e62b8b6d2f45a79652238b33f4bbe23023004ae7/tmp-target-install/home/martin/Downloads/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 19 bytes  received 12 bytes  62,00 bytes/sec

total size is 0  speedup is 0,00

rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]

make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:374: /home/martin/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/qt5quickcontrols-e62b8b6d2f45a79652238b33f4bbe23023004ae7/.stamp_target_installed] Error 23
```

Any idea how to fix it?